# How to Get Current Logged User Email in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

How to Get Current Logged User Email in Azure Dev Ops.

I want to get the email of the current user who deployed the job.

I am new to this so I am not sure how to try this i know how to set variables in variable group and call that variable to my job

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the email of the current user who deployed the job.

To meet your requirement, you can directly use the Predefined variables in Azure DevOps.

For build Pipeline, you can use the variable: `$(Build.RequestedForEmail)`

For release Pipeline, you can use the variable:`$(Release.RequestedForEmail)` or `$(Release.Deployment.RequestedForEmail)`.

These variables can directly be used in Pipelines without variable groups.

For more detailed info, you can refer to the docs: [Classic release and artifacts variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) and [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)